# Will a transactional annotated method overridden in a sub-interface still start a transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Consider this scenario for a Java application with Spring:

```
public interface FooDao {
    @Transactional
    void save(Foo foo);
}

public interface SecureFooDao extends FooDao {
    @Secured({Role.ADMIN})
    void save(Foo foo);
}
```

My question is this; will calling save on a SecureFooDao interface start a transaction, or will it ignore the overriden methods annotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Spring reference [10.5.6 Using @Transactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

> Tip
>
> **Spring recommends that you only annotate concrete classes (and methods of concrete classes) with the @Transactional annotation**, as opposed to annotating interfaces. You certainly can place the @Transactional annotation on an interface (or an interface method), but this works only as you would expect it to if you are using interface-based proxies. The fact that Java annotations are not inherited from interfaces means that if you are using class-based proxies (proxy-target-class="true") or the weaving-based aspect (mode="aspectj"), then the transaction settings are not recognized by the proxying and weaving infrastructure, and the object will not be wrapped in a transactional proxy, which would be decidedly bad.

So even not overriden it will only work if you use Spring-Aop-Proxies (*which I can not recommend*), but not for AspectJ or CGILib Proxies!

But I do not expect that this work for an method that is overriden in an Interface, even not for Spring-Aop-Proxies.